# Java: Prevent duplicate class by returning existing class during initialization

Tags: java, database, initialization

I am creating a class that, when created, is automatically added to a list. I don't want the list to have duplicate classes with the same class variable `name`. I would like to check the list at the beginning of the constructor and if the list contains a duplicate, then I want the new class to simply point to that duplicate instead of returning a new class. Here is my code:

```
private Country(int newID, String name) {
    Country duplicate = Country.getByName(name);

    if (duplicate == null) {
        String activeUsername = (activeUser != null) ? activeUser.getUsername() : "NULL";

        LocalDate creationDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDateTime lastUpdated = LocalDateTime.now();

        set(newID, name, creationDate, activeUsername, lastUpdated, activeUsername);

        if (newID > 0) {
            insert();
            addToList();
        }
    } else {
        this = duplicate; //<== this is the part I can't seem to get right.
    }
}
```

Please note that I don't want it to simply create a new instance with the same values, I want it to actually point to the one that is already in the list.

EDIT: My database has the UNIQUE constraint and I don't want to violate it.

Comment: Do you mean duplicate classes or duplicate objects?

Comment: I don't want two `Country` class objects both with the same `name` variable. If the list already has a `Country` class object with the same `c.name`, then I want the new `Country` class object to simply point to the existing `Country` class object.

Comment: I'm confused here - by class object, do you mean `Class` objects?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this in a constructor. However, you can write a factory function that conditionally returns an existing object or a new object.

Add a new static function called create to your class and move your code there.